# Keep the table value in a variable by table id where the table value is inputted by user

Tags: php

My code:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
        $count++;
        $row8= mysqli_fetch_array($result8);
echo "<td><input id=".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']." name=".$row['StudentID'].'['. $row8['MarksID']."]s type='text'></td>";

    $ID[$count]= $_POST[$row['StudentID'].'['.$row8['MarksID'].']'];
}
```

this code is in a for loop. For the every value of the table id is being changed. I want to get the value of the table column from the variable `$ID[$count]`. but this code is not working.

Comment: It should be syntax error: { count++; ?Could you paste whole loop code ?

Comment: *"but this code is not working. What can I do"* - check for errors, run a var_dump and look at your html source

Comment: You really need to verify the line after count++, it's riddled with errors.

Comment: @VirCom whole loop is being pasted.

Comment: Ok, so please paste your example $_POST content. I think, something is wrong in here: $row['StudentID'].'['.$row8['MarksID'].']'

Comment: example $_POST content ?? i couldn't understand ... please explain